# Member template for user defined types

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a simple example below where AddField() is the member template.

What do I need to do to make AddField(T) work with either user defined types or a type such as vector. It works fine with primitive types.

```
class Data
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void AddField(T val)
    {
        std::stringstream s;
        s << val;
        m_data += s.str();
    }

private:
    std::string m_data;
};

class A    
{
public:
    A(int val) : m_k(val) {}
private:
    int m_k;
};


int main() {
    Data x;
    // Add basic types
    x.AddField(1);
    x.AddField("_");
    x.AddField(0.5);

    **// Add a vector**
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(99);
    x.AddField(v);    <==== Not OK 

   **// Add a user defined type**
    A a(-45);
    x.AddField(a);    <==== Not OK

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should edit your post to include any compile errors you get, but I suspect one of them would be how there's no operator << for `std::vector`, nor for `A`. If a class doesn't define such an operator, then it won't be 'serializable' in the way you're trying to do. You can define such operators yourself (and operator>> to get the data back out), but that would be required for _every_ class you want to store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an `operator<<()` for vectors (by example

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream& s, std::vector<T> const & v)
 { for ( auto const & e : v ) s << e; return s; }
```

) and one for `A` (by example, if you add in `A` a `get_m_k()` method,

```
std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream& s, A const & a)
 { return s << a.get_m_k(); }
```